# Can anyone help me understand the matches to this regular expression?

Tags: regular-expressions

My professor gave us this pattern "/[aeiou]+[1234567890]*[a-z]?/" and I'm trying to find matches in "ae12abc r2d2 a1steaksauce".

The resulting matches the professor gave us are ae12a, a1s, eak, auc, and e.

I think I'm totally misunderstanding how this is supposed to work. Why are ae12abc, r2d, or a1steaksauce not possible matches? Thanks in advance, I really appreciate any help with this!

Comment: An important question is, do you want all matches or just maximal matches?

Answer (score 4):

Well let's walk through it. You need one or more vowels, followed by any number of numbers (including *none*), followed by (optionally) a letter.

`ae` matches your vowels, `12` matches the numbers, then `a` counts as your optional letter. The engine starts again and looks for the next vowel. It skips `bc r2d2` since there are no vowels there.

Then it finds `a` for your vowels, `1` for your numbers, and `s` as the optional letter. Then the engine starts again and looks for the next vowel.

It finds `ea` for your vowels. There are no numbers, so it grabs `k` as the optional letter. Then it starts again looking for vowels...

Answer (score 2):

Why `ae12abc` is not a match: `ae` matches the `[aeiou]+` part of the regexp, `12` matches the `[1234567890]*` part, but `abc` doesn't match `[a-z]?`, because  `[a-z]?` matches the empty string or any single letter, and `abc` is not a single letter.

Why `a1steaksauce` is not a match: the same reason.  `steaksauce` is not a single letter.

Why `r2d` is not a match: `r` doesn't match `[aeiou]+`.